# Нужно узнать сколько сессий открыл каждый пользователь в среде UNIX

Tags: linux, unix

Задали задачку в универе, вывести с помощью потока список залогиненых пользователей, отсортировать его по алфавиту и посчитать сколько у кого открыто сессий, первые два пункта мне под силу, а вот третий совершенно не понимаю откуда копать

Comment: **w, who, last, ps, pgrep -u** вам в помощь. под ссесиями, думаю понимать нужно количество tty запущенных?

Comment: и как же решаешь первые две пункта? не вижу, какие могут быть проблемы, с решением последнего, если они решены...

Comment: @Hellseher, всё же *pty*, я думаю.

Comment: Вся информация берётся из */proc*.